# Using Arrow Keys in C

Tags: c, text, arrow-keys

I've finally got a hold of the Arrow Keys in C. I've found out how to have C detect them and have actually made a program of it.

The problem is... The program is bugged. I don't know what I've done wrong.

CODE:

```
#include <stdio.h>
main()
{
    char menitem[3][32], key, key2;
    int i = 0;
    strcpy(menitem[0], "Option 1 [X]");
    strcpy(menitem[1], "Option 2 [ ]");
    strcpy(menitem[2], "Option 3 [ ]");
    start:
    system("cls");
    printf("%s\n%s\n%s", menitem[0], menitem[1], menitem[2]);
    key = getch();
    key2 = 0;
    if(key = 0xE0)
    key2 = getch();
    ret:
    if(i == 0)
    {
         switch(key2)
         {
        case 80:
            strcat(menitem[0], "\b\b ]");
            i++;
            strcat(menitem[i], "\b\bX]");
            goto start;
        default: goto ret;
     }
}
else if(i == 2)
{
     switch(key2)
    {
    case 72:
        strcat(menitem[2], "\b\b ]");
        i--;
        strcat(menitem[i], "\b\bX]");
        goto start;
        default: goto ret;
    }
}
else
{
    switch(key2)
    {
        case 80:
        strcat(menitem[i], "\b\b ]");
        i++;
        strcat(menitem[i], "\b\bX]");
        goto start;
        case 72:
        strcat(menitem[i], "\b\b ]");
        i--;
        strcat(menitem[i], "\b\bX]");
        goto start;
        default: goto ret;
    }
}
}
```

Here's the problem:

When I go up from Option 2, Option 3 turns into "X]". Any idea why?

Try compiling it and keep on using the arrow keys. See what happens. Will appreciate any help given!

Comment: What is your problem exactly???

Comment: What platform is this? Arrow keys are not part of C, per se, but the host environment.

Comment: "Run my code to see the problem" is not something you are supposed to ask in SO question. Also, fix indentation (TAB char is problematic at SO). Turn on warnings for your compiler *and fix them*.

Comment: And about using **goto** to implement loops... While anything goes when you're coding for yourself for fun, be aware that nearly all programmers will shun any code which does that.

Comment: `if(key = 0xE0)` => `if(key == 0xE0)`

Comment: @hyde Sorry 'bout that. I'm not at all too experienced. I find it confusing to do properly "Structured Programming". I don't even know how to use pointers...

Answer (score 1):

Doing /b and erasing input, then adding input back, over and over, is not a good idea. For one, if the user presses lots of arrow keys, you'll get tons of backspaces/erased characters and your strings will grow very large. You are having problems because you are deleting too many characters in certain situations. Instead, just do a memory modification of the character inside the []. I will edit this post with a working solution.

**Edit** Here is a working solution:

```
#include <stdio.h>
int main()
{
    char menitem[3][32], key, key2;
    int i = 0;
    int currentlySelectedItem = 1;
    strcpy(menitem[0], "Option 1 [X]");
    strcpy(menitem[1], "Option 2 [ ]");
    strcpy(menitem[2], "Option 3 [ ]");
    while(1)
    {
        system("cls");
        printf("%s\n%s\n%s", menitem[0], menitem[1], menitem[2]);
        key = getch();
        key2 = 0;
        if(key == -32)
        {
            key2 = getch();
        }
        else
        {
            continue;
        }
        if(key2 == 80)
        {
            currentlySelectedItem++;
        }
        else if(key2 == 72)
        {
            currentlySelectedItem--;
        }

        //make sure the selected item stays in range
        if(currentlySelectedItem < 1)
            currentlySelectedItem = 1;
        if(currentlySelectedItem > 3)
            currentlySelectedItem = 3;

        menitem[0][10] = ' ';
        menitem[1][10] = ' ';
        menitem[2][10] = ' ';
        menitem[currentlySelectedItem-1][10] = 'X';

    }

}
```

Comment: Windows.h is not needed for anything you are using. Also, it's `int main`, not `void`.

Comment: Incorrect. Windows.h is needed for this line: `system("cls");`.

You are correct about int main though. I've fixed that.

Comment: Nah. In DevC++, system(""); works even without windows.h

Comment: @George: it's not just DevC++, `system()` itself is standard C, `windows.h` is not needed for that. `cls` is Windows-specific (and you shouldn't use it - well, in general typically you'll want to avoid `system` *period*), but that's handled by `cmd.exe`, `windows.h` is not involved in any way.

Comment: Interesting. Thanks for the clarification :)

It's probably because I'm using the VS C++ compiler, but it won't compile if I don't include at least stdlib.h; I get the following error: `"error C3861: 'system': identifier not found"`

Comment: @George: that error is correct, `system()` is declared in `stdlib.h`.

Comment: Yup, if I use the VS C compiler it works without the additional includes. I will modify my answer again!